# Android XML Parser isnt working

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I am writing an android application with a XML parser.
I have a parser that used to work but when I run it it isnt doing anything.
This is my class:

```java
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class XMLParsingUsingDomeActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(1);


TextView ID[];
TextView vraag[];
TextView category[];
TextView a1[];
TextView p1[];
TextView a2[];
TextView p2[];
TextView a3[];
TextView p3[];

try {

URL url = new URL(
"http://128.140.217.126/vragen.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dbu= dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dbu.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

ID = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
vraag = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
category = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
a1 = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
p1 = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
a2 = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
p2 = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
a3 = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
p3 = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

Node node = nodeList.item(i);

ID[i] = new TextView(this);
vraag[i] = new TextView(this);
category[i] = new TextView(this);
a1[i] = new TextView(this);
p1[i] = new TextView(this);
a2[i] = new TextView(this);
p2[i] = new TextView(this);
a3[i] = new TextView(this);
p3[i] = new TextView(this);


Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("ID");
Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
ID[i].setText(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());


NodeList vraagList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("vraag");
Element vraagElement = (Element) vraagList.item(0);
vraagList = vraagElement.getChildNodes();
vraag[i].setText(((Node) vraagList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

NodeList a1List = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("a1");
Element a1Element = (Element) a1List.item(0);
a1List = a1Element.getChildNodes();
a1[i].setText(((Node) a1List.item(0)).getNodeValue());

NodeList p1List = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("p1");
Element p1Element = (Element) p1List.item(0);
p1List = p1Element.getChildNodes();
p1[i].setText(((Node) p1List.item(0)).getNodeValue());

NodeList a2List = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("a2");
Element a2Element = (Element) a2List.item(0);
a2List = a2Element.getChildNodes();
a2[i].setText(((Node) a2List.item(0)).getNodeValue());

NodeList p2List = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("p2");
Element p2Element = (Element) p2List.item(0);
p2List = p2Element.getChildNodes();
p2[i].setText(((Node) p2List.item(0)).getNodeValue());

NodeList a3List = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("a3");
Element a3Element = (Element) a3List.item(0);
a3List = a3Element.getChildNodes();
a3[i].setText(((Node) a3List.item(0)).getNodeValue());

NodeList p3List = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("p3");
Element p3Element = (Element) p3List.item(0);
p3List = p3Element.getChildNodes();
p3[i].setText(((Node) p3List.item(0)).getNodeValue());



layout.addView(category[i]);
Toast.makeText(this,
        "ID:  " + i + "\n" +
        "Vraag: " + ((Node) vraagList.item(0)).getNodeValue() + "\n" +
        "A1: " + ((Node) a1List.item(0)).getNodeValue() + "\n" +
        "P2: " + ((Node) p1List.item(0)).getNodeValue() + "\n" +
        "A2: " + ((Node) a2List.item(0)).getNodeValue() + "\n" +
        "P2: " + ((Node) p2List.item(0)).getNodeValue() + "\n" +
        "A3: " + ((Node) a3List.item(0)).getNodeValue() + "\n" +
        "P3: " + ((Node) p3List.item(0)).getNodeValue(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
}

/** Set the layout view to display */
setContentView(layout);

}
}
```

And my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your.pace.namace"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".XMLParsingUsingDomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the logcat output is worthless.
I didnt change the code but its just not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

What is the exception?

Couple of things can happen. It might be when you try to get URL from web service. Might be because you have to do your code in an AsyncTask.
I suggest you right click a line you suspect and Toggle Breakpoint, then go on your class in Package Explorer right-click it and go to "Debug As" then "Debug Configuration". Click Debug button after checking you're debugging the right project.

Welcome to debug mode, just try to see which line is causing the exception.